# How to set alternate row color in flex datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, colors

What is the method to set different colors for alternate rows in a flex datagrid? So that two adjacent rows are identified easily?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `alternatingItemColors` style. You can specify as many colors as you want in the array.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" alternatingItemColors="[#449933, #994433]"
    dataProvider="{[{d:'ASD', c:'$#'},{d:'WER', c:'^@'},{d:'VCB', c:'*!'}]}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="d"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="c"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

This [style](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#style:alternatingItemColors) takes effect only if no `backgroundColor` is specified.

Comment: Great.. Thank you.. I left out that work, thing I need to write some custom item renderer for it.. This is a lot easier .. Thanks :-) And your color sense isn't too bad ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I used itemRenderer into DataGridColumn

```
<mx:DataGrid>
   <mx:columns>
      <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="A" itemRenderer="com.shels.table.MarkObject"/>
      <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="B" />
   </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

```
package com.shels.table {

import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.geom.Matrix;

import mx.controls.Label;
import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.*;

public class MarkObject extends Label {

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        var g:Graphics = graphics;
        g.clear();

        var dField:String = DataGridListData(listData).dataField;
        var f:int = DataGridListData(listData).columnIndex;

        var c:int = 0xFFFFFF; 

        // c = parseInt( data[ "color"]);
        // You can to use field values from record.

        g.beginFill( c);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        g.endFill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use the `DataItemBound(Object, DataGridItemEventArgs)` event handler.

The Object in this event signature is the DataGrid control, so recast it and use `.DataGrid.Items.Count` modulo 2 to obtain a reference for when `.DataGridItemEventArgs.Item`is an alternate row.  I then created a css style for the alternate and changed `.DataGridItemEventArgs.Item.CssClass` to that newly created style.

The advantage with this method is that other row color manipulation can be done after this for highlighting; the `alternateItemColor` solution from above will always be the last css change before rendering, potentially overwriting any other highlighting.